# Custom value for zoom property in PHP/MySQL based Google Map is not working?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, yii2

I am trying to make PHP/MySQL based Google Map for my website. I am using zoom property value 7 for the map.

But after loading the map zoom property value doesn't reflect there. Its always show the map in detailed zoom.

I am using Twitter Bootstrap 3+ for the design.

Here, I am adding my code bellow-

```
<div id="map" style="width: 280px; height: 248px;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var locations = [
         ['<h4><?php echo $name; ?></h4>', <?php echo $lat;?>, <?php echo $lng; ?> ],
];

// Setup the different icons and shadows
var iconURLPrefix = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/';

var icons = [
  iconURLPrefix + 'red-dot.png',
  iconURLPrefix + 'green-dot.png',
  iconURLPrefix + 'blue-dot.png',
  iconURLPrefix + 'orange-dot.png',
  iconURLPrefix + 'purple-dot.png',
  iconURLPrefix + 'pink-dot.png',      
  iconURLPrefix + 'yellow-dot.png'
]

var icons_length = icons.length;

var shadow = {
  anchor: new google.maps.Point(15,33),
  url: iconURLPrefix + 'msmarker.shadow.png'
};

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  zoom: 7,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $lat;?>, <?php echo $lng; ?>),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  mapTypeControl: false,
  streetViewControl: false,
  panControl: false,
  zoomControlOptions: {
    position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_BOTTOM
  }
});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  maxWidth: 160
});

var marker;
var markers = new Array();

var iconCounter = 0;

// Add the markers and infowindows to the map
for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    map: map,
    icon : icons[iconCounter],
    shadow: shadow
  });

  markers.push(marker);

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  })(marker, i));

  iconCounter++;
  // We only have a limited number of possible icon colors, so we may have to restart the counter
  if(iconCounter >= icons_length){
    iconCounter = 0;
  }
}

function AutoCenter() {
  //  Create a new viewpoint bound
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  //  Go through each...
  $.each(markers, function (index, marker) {
    bounds.extend(marker.position);
  });
  //  Fit these bounds to the map
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
AutoCenter();
```

I am assuming the issue occuring due to CSS code but not sure exactly how to resolve this.

Comment: The function AutoCenter probably will override the zoom

Answer (score 1):

The method map.fitBounds will override the initial zoom value. If you really want to define the zoom value you can get the center value from bounds and then set the center of the map with that value.

In AutoCenter() function you must remove map.fitBounds(bounds) and include var boundsCenter = bounds.getCenter(); map.setCenter(boundsCenter);

```
function AutoCenter() {
  //  Create a new viewpoint bound
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  //  Go through each...
  $.each(markers, function (index, marker) {
    bounds.extend(marker.position);
  });
  //  Fit these bounds to the map
  // map.fitBounds(bounds);

  // This will get bounds center
  var boundsCenter = bounds.getCenter();

  // center map
  map.setCenter(boundsCenter);
}
AutoCenter();
```